# Create a ServerConnection object to create an SMO server object in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, smo

I'm trying to establish a connection to SQL server to use SMO. In my local machine with option1, I'm able to connect with option 1. However I have to run the same in a server machine (with SQL Server and not SQL Server Express). I'm running as a Windows service in the server machine which should connect to SQL server. I tried the below options and multiple combinations I can think for connection string.

```
ServerConnection connection = GetServerConnection();
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

private ServerConnection  GetServerConnection()
{
  //Option 1
 ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("localhost\\SQLEXPRESS");

  //Option2
  ServerConnection connection =new ServerConnection("localhost");

  //Option3
  ServerConnection connection =new ServerConnection("DEVSRV02");

  //Option4
  ServerConnection connection =new ServerConnection();

  //Option5
  //string conStr1="Server=DEVSRV02;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
  //string conStr2="Data Source="(local)";Server=DEVSRV02;InitialCatalog=master; Trusted_Connection=True";
  //string conStr3="Dsn=AuditLog;uid=xxx;trusted_connection=Yes";
  //string conStr4="Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=DEVSRV02;Database=AuditLog;Uid=xxx; Pwd=xxx;";
  //string conStr5="Server=DEVSRV02;Initial Catalog=AuditLog;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
  //string conStr6="Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=AuditLog;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
  //string conStr7="Data Source=DEVSRV02;InitialCatalog=master; Trusted_Connection=True";

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlCon = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr);
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);

return connection ;
}
```

With the username and password I used in connection string, I could successfully login using windows authentication option in SSMS manually.
I also created another login using SQL Server Authentication and no password, with which I'm able to login to SSMS manually.
However, I tried both these options in connection strings, and every time, I'm getting the below exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_DataSource()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionSettings.InitFromSqlConnection(SqlConnection sc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor(SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject, IRenewableToken accessToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection..ctor(SqlConnection sqlConnection, IRenewableToken accessToken)
   at EmailReader.SiteSpecificDatabaseBuilder.GetServerConnection()
```

Any hints on what I'm missing?

Comment: The Windows authentication option doesn't do username/password at all. It uses the authentication token issued when you logged into the computer.

Comment: When you specify a Username and Password in a connection string that's using SQL Logon authentication. You don't include usernames and passwords in connection strings when you wish to use Windows authentication - the process needs to be executed under that account, such as by using `runas`, Scheduled Tasks, or registering it as a service with those logon credentials.

Comment: You are probably using a controller.  The front end from client to server will pass windows credentials (not username and password) like comments above.  Than your backend connection string has to use "Integrated Security = True" which is Windows Credentials instead of username and password.  To verify everything is working properly SQL Server Management Studio explorer under Management has a log file.  The log file will show the group/user that logged in.  If you fail the connection always check the log which will give the user account that attempted the login.

Comment: Try `.` as the server name. For Windows Authentication the account that the service runs under needs SQL permissions.